# Why are there seams all over the mesh when a Normal Map is applied?

Tags: mesh, texture-baking, normals

I am making a **game asset**, so first I made a high poly model and then Decimated the duplicate using the *Decimate* modifier. Then I baked the **Normals** of the High Poly model on to the Low Poly model and gave the generated normal map to the Low Poly model. Worked pretty decent ignoring the fact that there were seams all over the model.

[image]
[image]
[image]

*p.s. don't mind the different colours that just texture*

In Edit mode below:

[image]

*Also incase some of you might be concerned, converting Tris to Quads did **not** help

I don't know should I Unwrap the mesh again or add more geometry, but it is already 7000 Faces, its already a lot for a game asset.

*The Alpha was checked all along, but the problems still seams to appear.I tried unchecking and checking Alpha, but nothing changes. Also I've noticed that the seams are mostly on the places where my edges in edit mode are, I dont know what that could mean, maybe the Normals map is not strong enough though it is on MAX

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Save the normal map externally. Then select "usa alpha" in the texture properties and this gets rid of issues with margins and rendering.

Comment: @Aidan Pallian if you mean to check Alpha under the Influence > Diffuse. Unfortunately this didn't change anything.

Comment: No, after you save it, there should be a "use alpha" checkbox in the texture properties.

Comment: I found it and seems like it was checked all along

Comment: Uncheck it. then it should work.

Comment: I tried unchecking and checking Alpha, but nothing changes. Also I've noticed that the seams are mostly on the places where my edges in edit mode are, I dont know what that could mean, maybe the Normals map is not strong enough though it is on MAX

Comment: It did make it slightly better, but most of the places still have seams

Comment: Sometimes closing and reopening blender can fix the issue.

Comment: Is it more visible when zoomed out?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/28872/discussion-between-igor-tatarnikov-and-aidan-pallian).